# From Excel to Outlook: how to do the link especially with files such as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

***First a few words of context:***

In my company we always have to attach 3 PDF files when it comes to sending an e-mail (by Outlook) to a client regarding a product. Sometimes when we speak about several products, we have to send even more PDF files. Hopefully some files are redundant because they are "family" of products but still it's really a mess.

Then I got the idea of creating an excel sheet with the list of all the products and all the associated PDFs to send. The idea is to tick the box of which files we want to send then click on the big email icon and all the chosen documents will be already attached to an e-mail in Outlook. After that all you have to do is to write the name of the client and you're done: send it!.

Having an idea is great but implementing it is better. That's where my Excel and VBA skills are lacking.

**Here are the questions:**

1.how to assign a pdf files to a "box"

2.how to create the link from Excel to an email in Outlook by simply clicking on the mail icon so that all chosen documents are attached in the email?

Here are the pictures that will help you understand the issue.

[image: Excel example]

[image: Outlook example]

Comment: This site is not to write code for you.  Start by writing some VBA code and then post a question when you have a specific question that you can't figure out.  For sending an email from Excel, start here: http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/excel-vba-send-a-excel-workbook-as-attachment-in-mail-from-ms-outlook-using-excel/

Comment: To assign the checkboxes to a pdf file, you need to name each checkbox, and then check to see if it's checked when making an email.  If checked, attach the appropriate file, if not, then don't.  I'd make constant variables with the filepath for each attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is almost right, but off a bit.  Please see the link below.  You should find your answer there.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm